Upload csv using Invoke-RestMethod
I am trying to upload a local csv file to the import endpoint of 4me/xurrent using power shell. My latest version looks as follows and still receives an error.
$importUrl = "https://api.xurrent.qa/v1/import"
# Create the headers for the import request
$ImportHeaders = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $bearerToken"
    "X-4me-Account" = "XXX"
    "Content-Type" = "multipart/form-data"
}
# Create the body for the import request
$importBody = @{
    file = $ImportFile
    type = "cis"
}
#QA Import to Xurrent with PROXY
$importResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $importUrl -Headers $ImportHeaders -inFile $importBody

This get's the following error:
Invoke-RestMethod : Der Pfad "C:\Users\XXX\System.Collections.Hashtable" kann nicht gefunden werden, da er nicht vorhanden ist.
In \\tst_mgmt\4me_Import_Share\Scripts\QA - Import CI.ps1:65 Zeichen:19
+ ... tResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $importUrl -Headers $ ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\XXX...tions.Hashtable:String) [Invoke-RestMethod], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

ImportBody looks like this:
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                 
file                           C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\XXX.csv                                                                                                                       
type                           cis  


-InFile takes a file path as it's argument. Change -inFile $importBody to -InFile $ImportFile

Thanks for clarification @MathiasR.Jessen
How would I then pass on the type=cis parameter? I can't include -InFile and -Body in the same call?

Have you tried Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $importUrl -Method Post -Headers $ImportHeaders -Body $importBody ?
